# How to remove http:// in .tpl file?

Tags: php, string, http, templates, str-replace

How i can remove http://  in **html page** output is http://example.org

I just want to see it without http:// and www  if possible, i just need to see it. in output html page **[example.org](http://example.org)**
I got this code from .tpl file

```
<a href="{$listing.view_list_url}" >{$listing.record.url}</a>
```

Help me

Comment: Which CMS/framework do you use?

Comment: This file is using PHP

Comment: And TPL file is handled by which CMS/framework? Drupal, Wordpress, Joompla? Can you share code which generates those `$listing` variables? If you asking in plain PHP, the easiest way is to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace), e.g. `$listing.record.url = str_replace("http://", "", $listing.record.url);`, but you've to find the backend code responsible for this first.

Comment: 1st one its not working for me, the method is right but no, idea how do i apply, if i apply same, thats not working in this file....yes its php...i got a code "<p class="clsSiteLink"><a href="{$myobj->listing_details.url}" target="_blank">{$myobj->listing_details.url}</a></p>"

Comment: Your code is not complete, `$listing.record.url` is PHP variable within HTML code which is defined somewhere else in your code. Usually you don't add any parsers into your TPL file, you've to check where these variables are coming from.

Comment: Yes mate, i got your point, thank you.....now i trying to search back-end code....sorry i'm a PHP beginner

Comment: If it's Linux, try: `grep -Rn listing .` or `grep -Rn view_list_url .` within the directory where is the code.

Comment: Thank you str_replace code is working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove part of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192170/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string)